# Getting info on an enum type

Tags: c, enums

I have 2 enum types:

```
typedef enum {a=0, a1=3, a2=5} NX;
typedef enum {c=-1, c1=4, c2=7} NY;
```

I'd like to write an expression, that given a name of enum type/instance would return me the value of its first element. A possible solution is to always add fixed-name elements like

```
typedef enum {a=0, first=a, a1, a2, last=a2}
```

but, maybe there is a more elegant way.

Is there a way to get number of elements in the enum in run-time?

Comment: The same question for C++: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/159018/335858). Summary: your approach is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, `sizeof()` does not work on enum's. It is not possible to get number of elements in runtime.
There is one popular approach to check enum's last element value to determine amount of elements in a given enum, i.e.:

```
enum Type {A = 0, B, C, LAST};
printf("'Type' enum has %d number of elements", LAST);
```

Comment: Sure, this is valid only for sequential enum's.

Comment: Note: valid for sequential enums **whose first element is 0**.

Comment: Yes, but this can be easily calculated as you've pointed out in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in the enum are sequential (and in your first two examples they are) you can always use

```
typedef enum {first = -18, b, c, d, last } BlahBlah;
(...)
int nptElements = last - first + 1;
```

to get the number of elements. This, of course, requires knowledge of the first and last...

Comment: Sure, but I don't want to rely on enum value names in the code. I wonder if there is a compiler built-in way, working on any enum.

Comment: Then, as far as I know, either you store the information you need in the enum itself (or in a series of #defines or variables) or you use an array, in which case you loose the labeling feature.

Comment: You also have the c++ overkill in the stl::map container.