# MFC C++ insert enum values to CArray

Tags: c++, mfc, enums

How can i iterate over the values inside an enum and insert them to CArray (as their int).
OR
How can i determine number of values in a enum.

My goal: From:
enum MyEnum{DISCONNECTED=0,CONNECTED=1);
To:
CArray that have 2 entries with the enum ints.

Thanks !
The 2nd questions is impossible, I need it because i have generic class that i use for many projects and since i cannot send enum to that class in generic proper way, i will send a CArray that play the same rule as the enum values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max and min values in a C++ enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159006/max-and-min-values-in-a-c-enum)

Comment: Hi, thanks almost the same, but what if my values in int are not sequential, disconnected=2, connected=5, and i want in the CArray to have the entries of: (2,2) (5,5)

Comment: That just makes it worse. :-( There is no way to do that automatically. You *could* override `operator++` for your enum and skip the missing values, but still nothing that works automatically.

Comment: Please ask only 1 question at a time.  If you have 2 specific questions, they should each be in their own post.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but I don't see why you would need to. Enum values are constants, so you can simply go look at the definition of the enum and see the values for yourself :)